# Limit SQL query based on memory size of a column

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL table "Document" with a text column that stores serialized data ("content"). Sometimes this content is 1 KB, sometimes it is 3 MB, etc. Usually I have a good estimate of how big it is based on another column ("content_type"). For example, if its content_type is "history", the content is around 1 MB.

I have a REST endpoint where the client will request all of the records in the Document table that they are missing. For memory purposes I cant respond with all of the Documents at once. How can I limit the query such that I respond with a reasonable chunk of records (Lets say 50 MB worth) at a time?

I tried using a UNION for each content_type so that I could specify a different LIMIT for each union query, but I may have hundreds of different content_types so it does not seem like an option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try using a window function to to keep a running total of bytes.  In this example I just order it by `document.id`.  I would expect you to use some form of pagination, instead.

```
with sized as (
  select *, sum(length(content)) over (order by id) as running_bytes
    from document
)
select *
  from sized
 where running_bytes < 50 * 1024 * 1024;
```

For pagination support, I would extend it with another CTE:

```
with ordered as (
  select *, row_number() over (order by id) as rn
    from document
), sized as (
  select *, sum(length(content)) over (order by rn) as running_bytes
    from ordered
   where rn > <offset goes here>
)
select *
  from sized 
 where running_bytes < 50 * 1024 * 1024;
```

Comment: these are the results I want - this query takes very long but I can try figuring out something similar. Thank you

Comment: @Chicowitz I am not sure whether calculating the `length()` is optimized.  You *might* be better off adding a column to hold the length of `content` and maintain it with a trigger.

Comment: Im only familiar with basic pagination. A simple select from document limit x offset y doesnt work for this table, but if there is a more sophisticated way I'm all ears

Comment: @Chicowitz  Interestingly, Bruce Momjian has been discussing this the last couple of weeks on his blog:  https://momjian.us/main/blogs/pgblog/2020.html  I do not see why you would not be able to paginate the results of a query from this table if you wrap the ordering and filtering query into a CTE as we did here to get `running_bytes`.  You would need only `offset` since `running_bytes` provides the `limit`.  Instead of retrieving contents like this, how about keeping a list of `document.id` in a session variable and feed the docs sequentially as download processes should limit parallelism.

Comment: So the 2nd page would be.. select * from sized where running bytes BETWEEN 50 * 1024 * 1024 AND 2 * 50 * 1024 * 1024 ?  I can see how the document table could have a column called running bytes that gets updated on some interval to avoid that sum() calculation if thats what you meant

Comment: @Chicowitz  I added a pagination example.  The ordering you use would be implemented in the `ordered` cte, and the `offset` value would be injected into the `sized` cte.

Comment: Your solution will work, but the query is not very efficient.